# Python fast calculating and slow Serial writing : Multithread or Multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, robotics

I have a robotics project, basically a path tracking problem.
In PC, a reference generation algorithm is implemented in Python3.65. The algorithm takes Indoor GPS data and use these continuously-updated data to calculate the reference path for a robot-car. Of course, the algorithm runs in a 
***while True:
   ....***
framework.
The algorithm can work well only if the sampling frequency is quite high, say 0.001s. 
However, the problem is that, after calculating the reference path, the path info needs to be written to Serial port of the PC, byte by byte, via Serial.write(). 
This serial.write() function is still a for loop. And this writing process is very slow (more than 0.02s for 16 bytes). If the for loop is included in the while True: framework, something like：

---

```
while True:
  Data = Ref_generation()
  Bytes_Full = Float_2_Bytes_List(Data)
  for ele in Bytes_Full:
    Serial.write(ele)  # VERY SLOW!!!
  sleep(0.001)
```

---

Then, the Data can not be calculated correctly since the cycle period is much longer than 0.001s.

In a nutshell, how can I separate the fast calculating algorithm from the slow serial.wtite()? I tried multithreads, but not works.

Anyhelp will be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I used **daemon thread** for running Serial communication part. So try running Serial communication on a daemon thread which will run in the background of the host process. This will enable your program to run tasks in while independently of the wait time required for Serial communication. This way you can separate fast calculating algorithm from the slow serial.wtite().

You can find more about daemon thread [here](http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/). Further to avoid buffer lag you can use `reset_output_buffer()` from pySerial.

Comment: Hi J J. Thanks for your response. Well, I did use Daemon, but the result was not improved.

Comment: J.J Thanks for your attention. Well, the data send from PC to robot car goes through an RFID hardware whose maximal baudrate is 19200. This is a hard constraint.

Comment: @ZejiangWang It is hard to believe that by introducing daemon thread it is still not able to reduce loop execution time. Anyway, Have you tried reducing serial write timeout?

Comment: @ZejiangWang, Are you using struct module to convert float to byte?

Comment: Well for the thread method, I am not sure if I did what you meant. In a main() function, there were two functions (calculate and serial.write) , each of them associated with a different thread. Then in the main() function the two threads start . Of course, the serial.write function is set as daemon. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, what you did is correct, can you please share time required for the loop execution when a. multi-threading not used and b. multi-threading used. This will clear out the problem.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right. I made a mistake when I finally draw the graph in Matlab. Thanks a lot for your patience and time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to leverage multiple cpu cores, all you want is to **wait** for the serial port... Your CPU will be idle, **waiting**... Spawning new threads/processes to just **wait** is a waste...

That's why you should try to use some asynchronous IO solution.

Example, use https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial-asyncio or https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.1.0/api/twisted.internet.serialport.SerialPort.html

These asynchronous frameworks allow you to register events and have your function called automatically when they finish, **all in a single thread/process**.

They also allow you to schedule events in the time you want.

Comment: Hi Nosklo! Thanks for your swift response. I am not a CS guy, could you please explain a little bit more why multithread/process doesn't work for this case? If I can make the Data = Ref_generation() run continuously in background, with its own sampling frequency and use another thread/subprocess to access its result, can not I ensure that the data received is always good?

Comment: @ZejiangWang hello! It would "work" but it is a waste. See, processes are intended to process, but in your case, one of the processes won't actually **do** anything, it will just stay there waiting for the serial port to write the data! That is a waste of resources, since if you just don't wait, you can do other things while the serial port is writing, all in the **same process/thread**! To not wait, you use asynchronous framework that includes an event loop.

Comment: Hello nosklo. Thanks a lot for your patient answer.  I guess I understand. But as I said before, the more important issue in my case is that the slow serial.write() in fact affects negatively my high-frequency calculation. That's why I want to separate these two tasks. If I use an asynchronous I/O, I guess this issue still remains, no?

Comment: you can't make `serial.write` faster. what you can do is continue calculating while `serial.write` is slowly writing. That can be achieved with asynchronous IO. @ZejiangWang

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but the learning curve of the asyncro_serial  is quite steep for me. Do you have some very easy implementation example? For example, all I need is to fix necessary serial configuration ('COM', Baudrate, timeout, RTS = 0, etc) and serial.write() a byte array , byte by byte.